# Zoomable icicle d3 right to left

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to change alignment of this [link](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1005873) from right to left?

now alignment is top to bottom

Comment: specify a bit more please? alignment of what?

Comment: now alignment is top to bottom

Comment: I answered your original, laconic question. Your edit made little sense to me.

Comment: I think I (maybe) got what you want: you want the parent to be at the right and the children to be positioned on the left of their parents... It's hard to tell if you don't have the trouble of properly formulating your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);
```

It has to be:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([width, 0]);
```

Edit: if you want the icicles going from the right to the left (parents at the right, children at the left), this is what you have to do:

First, invert the range of the y scale:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height,0]);
```

And invert all the attributes of the rectangles:

```
rect = rect
  .data(partition(d3.entries(root)[0]))
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("y", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return x(d.dx); })
  .attr("width", function(d) { return y(d.dy); })
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).key); })
  .on("click", clicked);
```

Here is a fiddle showing it: https://jsfiddle.net/dLeq2q2d/

PS: the zoom will not work anymore, you'll have to change it as well.

Comment: Yes, this has to be it.

Comment: So, change the zoom function.

Comment: As this is another issue, I suggest you post another question. If you post another question specifying this issue, you'll get help faster.